# Is it possible to change color scheme for rviz map display?

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to create a customized color scheme for map display with rviz. I see that 3 schemes are supported: map, costmap, and raw. However, is there a way for adding more color schemes without changing the source code and rebuilding? perhaps through the configuration file?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280778/is-it-possible-to-change-color-scheme-for-rviz-map-display?/) by [murad](https://answers.ros.org/users/33418/murad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-01-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you would Need to either add a new Display type (i.e. [creating a new plugin for rviz](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/display_plugin_tutorial.html) or Change/Augment the exisiting map Display type.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [murad](https://answers.ros.org/users/33418/murad/) on 2018-01-25**:
Thanks for the answer!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-01-25**:
@murad please accept the answer above using the checkmark so that others know that it's been answered without needing to read your comment.